# Why can I ping a server but not connect via SSH?

Tags: ssh, ping

When I ping my server, it responds:

```
user@localhost:~$ ping my.server
PING my.server (111.111.111.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from my.server (111.111.111.11): icmp_req=1 ttl=42 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from my.server (111.111.111.11): icmp_req=2 ttl=42 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from my.server (111.111.111.11): icmp_req=3 ttl=42 time=58.6 ms
^C
--- my.server ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.419/49.037/58.637/8.287 ms
```

but when I try to ssh (something that I always do, and have been doing for the past few hours on the same connection), it hangs:

```
user@localhost:~$ ssh my.server
```

http://speedtest.net says that my connection has 1.5 Mbps download and 0.4 Mbps upload speed.

Is there a reason that ssh hangs?

---

Results from suggestions provided in answers

from @nsfyn55

```
user@localhost:~$ telnetmy.server 22 
Trying 111.111.111.11...
Connected to my.server
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

from @vahid:

```
user@localhost:~$ nc -v -w 1 111.111.111.111 -z 22
nc: timeout cannot be negative
```

Comment: try `ssh -v` to see at which point it stops.

Comment: ping shows that there is something listening/answering at this address. ssh is a protocol for connecting to this machine, which requires ssh daemon to be up and running and a port (usually port 22) to be open.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker it stops at `debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master`

Comment: hmm thats quite a varied message tried googling it - lots comes back in regards to sequel-pro/ssh http://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/issues/detail?id=1095    - but then i wonder if you need to wait longer and see if anything else is returned I would also check the serverfault link out - you may need to set up a controller for persistent connections to this host- http://serverfault.com/questions/408416/openssh-disable-controlmaster-for-given-hostname

Comment: but i would try both methods outlined in the above post i.e. ControlMaster no as well as defining the other config one at a time restarting sshd (should be no need but for assurance) then to retry ssh -vakx hostname and give it time

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105800/not-able-to-ssh-to-another-computer-but-can-ping-it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

ping (ICMP protocol) and ssh are two different protocols.

1. It could be that ssh service is not running or not installed
2. firewall restriction (local to server like iptables or even sshd config lock down ) or (external firewall that protects incomming traffic to network hosting 111.111.111.111)

First check is to see if ssh port is up

```
nc -v -w 1 111.111.111.111 -z 22
```

if it succeeds then ssh should communicate if not then it will never work until restriction is lifted or ssh is started

Comment: I get "nc: timeout cannot be negative"

Comment: nc -v -w 1 localhost -z 22
Connection to localhost 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
you should see succeeded try removing the -w 1 so nc -v 1111.111.111.111 -z 22  - you need to succeed to be able to ssh - but reading below you can telnet to port 22 which makes it sound like you have some sshd config barring u from connecting either on the /etc/hosts.allow deny files defined as sshd: ip but more than likely /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowUsers user@ip1 user@iprange2.* risky   ---------- catch 22 being you need to be on remote server to check all this out

Comment: try ssh -vakx 111.111.111.111 and show us output or google error - it maybe passwordless and awaiting key or something

Comment: @Abe, maybe you misread the given command—there's a `1` after the `-w` and before the IP address.

Answer (score 6):

Find out two pieces of information

- Whats the hostname or IP of the target ssh server
- What port is the ssh daemon listening on (default is port 22)

`$> telnet <hostname or ip> <port>`

Assuming the daemon is up and running and listening on that port it should etablish a telnet session. Likely causes:

- The ssh daemon is not running
- The host is blocking the target port with its software firewall
- Some intermediate network device is blocking or filtering the target port
- The ssh daemon is listening on a non standard port
- A TCP wrapper is configured and is filtering out your source host

Comment: I get `user@localhost:~$ telnetmy.server 22<br\>
Trying 111.111.111.11...<br\>
Connected to my.server.<br\>
Escape character is '^]'.<br\>
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3<\br>Connection closed by foreign host.
` (where `<br\>` = newline)

Comment: sounds like the port is open. Now try ssh -v <user>@<hostname>

Answer (score -4):

On the server, try:

```
netstat -an
```

and look to see if `tcp port 22` is opened (use `findstr` in Windows or `grep` in Unix).

Comment: if I can't get on the server, I can't execute this line

Comment: How I will run this command if I can't access the server