# ssh: connect to host <site-name> port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, connection

the last command i ran on the host system was:
shutdown -h now

i got the following message:
The system is going down for halt NOW!
Connection to  closed by remote host.

---

I am unable to do ssh to it. Please let me know how can i connect back to my system.

Comment: If the server is turned off you can't `ssh` into it, can you?

Comment: no.. how can reach my system back

Comment: What kind of server is it? Where is it hosted? Who does system administration for you? You need to contact someone who has physical access to this machine so they can turn it back on.

Comment: I advise you to rewrite your question since it's not very clear what your real problem is.

Comment: nginx server, isnt there any other way.. I am just wondering if there is any other way i can turn it back on

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715233/why-can-i-ping-a-server-but-not-connect-via-ssh  may helps you

Comment: sorry didnt get you, PeteR..

Comment: @Nilesh telling me that the server machine runs a nginx server doesn't help very much. Is this a VPS or something like it?

Comment: did you try restarting it,

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke How can i restart it

Comment: /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke: You seem to be missing the point - it's a remote server and he's shut it down.

Comment: @Nilesh you might need to contact your service provider to work around this issue.

Comment: ya @Mauren.. i think that is the only way.. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Considering your server is a VPS and you have shut it down, the best option (if not the only) is to contact the service provider and ask for them to start your server again.

**EDIT:** as per PeteR suggestion, you may ask them to disable your permission to shut down this server, so that this issue never happens again.

Answer (score -1):

On the server, try:

```
netstat -an
```

Comment: Apparently, the server is offline.